# Find a point in a polytope that always cuts off a constant fraction of the polytope.

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, linear-programming

I have $k$ linear inequalities in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which we can express as $Ax \ge c$ (where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^k$).  Assume that the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfy this inequality is bounded.

I want a method of choosing a point $p$ in the polytope defined by these inequalities.  I want the method to have the following property:

There exists a fraction $0 < f < \frac{1}{2}$ such that every hyperplane through $p$ divides the polytope into two figures, each of which contain at least $f$ of the total original area of the polytope.

The catch: *$f$ cannot depend on $A$ or $c$*.  So I need a method that produces a point that always cuts the polytope into two regions, each of which contains (for example) at least 1/3 of the original area.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it seems I've committed a basic research fail and overlooked the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), which seems to solve all my problems.

Sorry for the quick question-and-self-answer.

Comment: For posterity, I would like to add: the fraction cut by the centroid is $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$.  This converges to $\frac{1}{e}$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$, so for simplicity, you can just use $\frac{1}{e}$ as the value for $f$.

Comment: This solved not only your problems. :-) [More than ten years ago I found a simple but non-algorythmic proof based on Helly theorem for not necessarily convex case with the exact fraction cut bound $1/(n+1)$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5789). And I was wondering about the convex case. Can you provide a link to the result on the fraction cut by the centroid? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexRavsky glad to hear it!  [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=1L4YO8vQNCEC&pg=PA311&lpg=PA311&dq=n-dimensional+binary+search+centroid&source=bl&ots=YulSIM-cMM&sig=zCUMr5IwgVB6CmmY-QU2FhDymEM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DwJvUY_MIcm40QGE6oGYAg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=polytope%20centroid&f=false) is my source - check equation 8.53 on page 293.  Unfortunately, the "proof is too complicated to be given here," but maybe it's in the references somewhere - I haven't checked.